# Updating Donut Graph Using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been working for a few hours now and I can't get my donut graph drawn with d3.js to update to new data.

My HTML is,

```
  <body>
    <div id="pie"></div>
    <script src="pie.js"></script>
  </body>
```

And my JS is,

```
var dataset = [40, 20];

var width = 460,
  height = 300,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = ['#000000', '#FFFFFF'];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

function render() {
  var pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null);

  var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - 100)
    .outerRadius(radius - 50);

  var path = svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(pie(dataset))
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color[i]; })
    .attr("d", arc);
}

render();

function update() {

  dataset[0] = 100;

  render();
}
```

Currently this draws the donut graph but whenever I call the `update()` function from the console, the dataset updates but the donut graph doesn't update on screen.

I've found some other examples for bar charts (using enter, append and exit) but I can't get them to work with my example.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, you are only updating the data, which will not change the chart. You also know that, for changing the chart, you'll have to set an "update" selection.

Right now, you just have an "enter" selection:

```
var path = svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(pie(data)).enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color[i]; })
    .attr("d", arc);
```

So, every time you change the `dataset`, nothing happens in your chart because your "enter" selection is empty. You could just select something that doesn't exist:

```
var path = svg.selectAll(".foo")
```

But this is a terrible solution, because you'll have a bunch of paths piling up in your SVG.

So, the best solution is creating an "enter" and an "update" selection:

```
//this binds the data:
var path = svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(pie(data));

//this is the "enter" selection:
var pathEnter = path.enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color[i]; })
    .attr("d", arc);

//this is the "update" selection:
var pathUpdate = path.attr("d", arc);
```

Check this demo:

```js
var dataset = [40, 20];

var width = 300,
    height = 200,
    radius = 150;

var color = ['#222', '#EEE'];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

function render(data) {
    var pie = d3.pie()
        .sort(null);

    var arc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius - 100)
        .outerRadius(radius - 50);

    var path = svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(pie(data));

    var pathEnter = path.enter().append("path")
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
            return color[i];
        })
        .attr("d", arc);

    var pathUpdate = path.attr("d", arc);


}

render(dataset);

setInterval(function() {
    update();
}, 2000);

function update() {

    dataset = [Math.random() * 50, Math.random() * 50];

    render(dataset);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="pie"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The concept is much clearer to me now. Well explained and it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/naveenrk/d3-donut-sanky-chart

[image: Donut and sanky chart Using Angular6, D3.js, and d3sankey.js]

[![Updated the donut chart with text displaying the center

```js
 const result = {
      'fleetView': [
        {
          'VesselName': 'MOL Emissary',
          'IMO': '07158',
          'QS': 'Good',
          'SeaState': 'Under Way using engine',
          'STW': '12.4/11.6',
          'DepPort': 'DK RNN',
          'ArrPort': 'DK RNN',
          'Course': '123',
          'Speed': '11.7 km',
          'CurrentDraught': '10 m',
          'Start': '2019-02-18T00:42:55Z',
          'End': '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z'
        },
        {
          'VesselName': 'Gulf Baynunah',
          'IMO': '9362',
          'QS': 'No connection',
          'SeaState': 'Under Way using engine',
          'STW': '7.0/7.6',
          'DepPort': 'No OSL',
          'ArrPort': 'No OSL',
          'Course': '180',
          'Speed': '20 km',
          'CurrentDraught': '20 m',
          'Start': '2019-02-18T01:48:03Z',
          'End': '2019-02-21T00:00:00Z'
        },
        {
          'VesselName': 'Desert Oasis',
          'IMO': '9782',
          'QS': 'Good',
          'SeaState': 'Contrained by her draught',
          'STW': '10/11',
          'DepPort': 'DK ANB',
          'ArrPort': 'DK ANB',
          'Course': '155',
          'Speed': '15 km',
          'CurrentDraught': '10 m',
          'Status': 'Good',
          'Start': '2019-02-18T01:48:49Z',
          'End': '2019-02-23T00:00:00Z'
        },
        {
          'VesselName': 'Maersk Montana',
          'IMO': '9312',
          'QS': 'Good',
          'SeaState': 'At anchor',
          'STW': '0/0',
          'DepPort': 'EN LND',
          'ArrPort': 'EN LND',
          'Course': '144',
          'Speed': '19 km',
          'CurrentDraught': '17 m',
          'Start': '2019-02-18T01:20:45Z',
          'End': '2019-02-21T00:00:00Z'
        },
        {
          'VesselName': 'New Elias',
          'IMO': '90',
          'QS': 'Bad',
          'SeaState': 'Contrained by her draught',
          'STW': '17.4/18.6',
          'DepPort': 'SE STK',
          'ArrPort': 'SE STK',
          'Course': '165',
          'Speed': '20 km',
          'CurrentDraught': '15 m',
          'Start': '2019-02-18T01:49:06Z',
          'End': '2019-02-21T00:00:00Z'
        },
        {
          'VesselName': 'MSC Bremen',
          'IMO': '',
          'QS': 'Good',
          'SeaState': 'Under Way using engine',
          'STW': '14.4/15.6',
          'DepPort': 'DK RNN',
          'ArrPort': 'DK RNN',
          'Course': '175',
          'Speed': '16 km',
          'CurrentDraught': '11 m',
          'Start': '2019-02-18T01:48:05Z',
          'End': '2019-02-20T00:00:00Z'
        },
        {
          'VesselName': 'Cornelia Maersk',
          'IMO': '',
          'QS': 'Poor',
          'SeaState': 'Under Way using engine',
          'STW': '4.0/4.0',
          'DepPort': 'ES MAD',
          'ArrPort': 'ES MAD',
          'Course': '111',
          'Speed': '21 km',
          'CurrentDraught': '10 m',
          'Start': '2019-02-18T01:50:10Z',
          'End': '2019-02-21T00:00:00Z'
        },
        {
          'VesselName': 'Elandra Oak',
          'IMO': '',
          'QS': 'Good',
          'SeaState': 'Under Way using engine',
          'STW': '10.4/11.6',
          'DepPort': 'DK RNN',
          'ArrPort': 'DK RNN',
          'Course': '180',
          'Speed': '20 km',
          'CurrentDraught': '11 m',
          'Start': '2019-02-18T01:49:21Z',
          'End': '2019-02-24T00:00:00Z'
        },
        {
          'VesselName': 'Pinza',
          'IMO': '',
          'QS': 'Good',
          'SeaState': 'Under Way using engine',
          'STW': '12.4/11.6',
          'DepPort': 'DK RNN',
          'ArrPort': 'DK RNN',
          'Course': '265',
          'Speed': '14 km',
          'CurrentDraught': '11 m',
          'Status': 'Good',
          'Start': '2019-02-18T01:49:37Z',
          'End': '2019-02-28T00:00:00Z'
        },
        {
          'VesselName': 'Mahadah Silver',
          'IMO': '',
          'QS': 'Good',
          'SeaState': 'Under Way using engine',
          'STW': '22.4/24.6',
          'DepPort': 'DK RNN',
          'ArrPort': 'DK RNN',
          'Course': '214',
          'Speed': '16 km',
          'CurrentDraught': '6 m',
          'Status': 'Good',
          'Start': '2019-02-18T01:47:51Z',
          'End': '2019-02-18T00:00:00Z'
        },
        {
          'VesselName': 'Atlantic Breeze',
          'IMO': '',
          'QS': 'Good',
          'SeaState': 'Under Way using engine',
          'STW': '14.4/16.6',
          'DepPort': 'DK RNN',
          'ArrPort': 'DK RNN',
          'Course': '178',
          'Speed': '18 km',
          'CurrentDraught': '12 m',
          'Status': 'Good',
          'Start': '2019-02-18T01:47:15Z',
          'End': '2019-02-25T00:00:00Z'
        },
        {
          'VesselName': 'Kronviken',
          'IMO': '',
          'QS': 'Good',
          'SeaState': 'Under Way using engine',
          'STW': '20.4/21.6',
          'DepPort': 'DK RNN',
          'ArrPort': 'DK RNN',
          'Course': '198',
          'Speed': '15 km',
          'CurrentDraught': '11 m',
          'Status': 'Good',
          'Start': '2019-02-18T01:45:54Z',
          'End': '2019-02-21T00:00:00Z'
        },
        {
          'VesselName': 'NS Stream',
          'IMO': '',
          'QS': 'Bad',
          'SeaState': 'Under Way using engine',
          'STW': '11.4/11.6',
          'DepPort': 'DK RNN',
          'ArrPort': 'DK RNN',
          'Course': '159',
          'Speed': '16 km',
          'CurrentDraught': '9 m',
          'Status': 'Good',
          'Start': '2019-02-17T22:56:15Z',
          'End': '2019-02-19T00:00:00Z'
        },
        {
          'VesselName': 'Maersk Shenzhen',
          'IMO': '',
          'QS': 'Poor',
          'SeaState': 'Under Way using engine',
          'STW': '15.4/16.6',
          'DepPort': 'DK RNN',
          'ArrPort': 'DK RNN',
          'Course': '256',
          'Speed': '21 km',
          'CurrentDraught': '20 m',
          'Status': 'Good',
          'Start': '2019-02-18T01:49:24Z',
          'End': '2019-02-23T00:00:00Z'
        },
        {
          'VesselName': 'Lambi',
          'IMO': '',
          'QS': 'Good',
          'SeaState': 'Under Way using engine',
          'STW': '25.5/26.6',
          'DepPort': 'DK RNN',
          'ArrPort': 'DK RNN',
          'Course': '297',
          'Speed': '21 km',
          'CurrentDraught': '11 m',
          'Status': 'Good',
          'Start': '2019-02-18T01:47:03Z',
          'End': '2019-02-28T00:00:00Z'
        }
      ]
    };

    function groupingBy(data, groupby) {
      return _.groupBy(data, groupby);
    }

    function getObjectKeys(groupByData) {
      return Object.keys(groupByData);
    }

    const newGroupValue = groupingBy(result.fleetView, 'SeaState');
    const newKeys = getObjectKeys(newGroupValue);

    const dataset = [];
    // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
    for (const k in newGroupValue) {
      const kk = { name: k, value: newGroupValue[k].length };
      dataset.push(kk);
    }
    const userSelectedColors = ['value'];
    const totalCount = _.sumBy(userSelectedColors, _.partial(_.sumBy, dataset));

    console.log(totalCount);


    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(newKeys)
      .range(['#8BC2CA', '#5CAAB5', '#B9DADF']);

    const pie = d3.pie()
      .value(function (d: any) { return d.value; })
      .sort(null)
      .padAngle(.03);

    const w = 250, h = 200;

    // donut size
    const outerRadius = 60;
    const innerRadius = 100;

    const arc = d3.arc()
      .outerRadius(outerRadius)
      .innerRadius(innerRadius);

    const svg = d3.select('#chart')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', w)
      .attr('height', h + 100)
      .attr('class', 'shadow')
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + w / 2 + ',' + h / 2 + ')');


    const path = svg.selectAll('path')
      .data(pie(dataset))
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', arc)
      .attr('fill', (d: any, i: any) => color(d.data.name));

    path.transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attrTween('d', function (d) {
        const interpolate = d3.interpolate({ startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0 }, d);
        return function (t) {
          return arc(interpolate(t));
        };
      });


    const restOfTheData = function () {
      const text = svg.selectAll('text')
        .data(pie(dataset))
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .attr('transform', function (d: any) {
          const _d = arc.centroid(d);
          _d[0] *= 1; // multiply by a constant factor
          _d[1] *= 1; // multiply by a constant factor
          return 'translate(' + _d + ')';
        })
        .attr('dy', '.50em')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .text((d: any) => {
          return d.data.value;
        });

      svg.append('text')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('font-size', '2.5em')
        .attr('y', 8)
        .text(totalCount);

        svg.append('text')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('font-size', '1.5em')
        .attr('y', 25)
        .text('vessel');

      const legendRectSize = 20;
      const legendSpacing = 7;
      const legendHeight = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;


      const legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
        .data(color.domain())
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', '.legend')
        .attr('transform', (d: any, i: any) => 'translate(-95,' + ((i * legendHeight) + 110) + ')');

      legend.append('rect')
        .attr('width', legendRectSize)
        .attr('height', legendRectSize)
        .attr('rx', 20)
        .attr('ry', 20)
        .style('fill', color);

      legend.append('text')
        .attr('x', 30)
        .attr('y', 15)
        .text(function (d) {
          return d;
        })
        .attr('fill', '#152935')
        .attr('font-size', '1.2em');
    };
    setTimeout(restOfTheData, 1000);
```

```html
/*
  Prerequisite - 
  "d3": "5.7.0",
  "d3-sankey": "^0.7.1",
  "lodash": "^4.17.11"
  */
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
// For Donut chart
<div id="chart" class="chart-container">
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfIS0.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfIS0.png)

Comment: The above is the code snippet, please do install and follow up the Prerequisite